# What is the origin of the dialogue "take me instead of her/him"?

Tags: first-appearance, dialogue

In many Hollywood horror movies the last climactic scene features the dialogue "take me instead". For example,  *Dark Water* (2005), *The Exorcist*  and *The Ring 2*.

So what is the origin of this famous dialogue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The theme of sacrifice oneself for another is quite common in film and literature, so finding the origin may be impossible.

However, searching [Subzin](http://www.subzin.com/search.php?title=&imdb=&q=%22Take%20me%20instead%22&search_sort=Oldest&genre=-1&type=All), the earliest mention I found of "take me instead" is from *The Battle of China* (1944):

> 1:34:30 General, I beg you to let the girl go
>   01:34:36 She is innocent
>   01:34:40 **Take me instead**

The first specifically horror film is *The Gate* (1987)

> 01:15:06 No!
>   01:15:08 Come back here!
>   01:15:11 **Take me instead!**
>   01:15:13 Come back!
>   01:15:15 What do you want? Another sacrifice?
>   01:15:17 Come back! **Take me instead.**
>   01:15:21 Come back.
>   01:15:23 Come back.